# Chrome Only Bootstrap + Google Maps Bug

Tags: html, google-maps, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Let me first say that the map is drawing correctly, this is not a duplicate of the other maps/bootstrap bug.

I am having an issue where a map on a twitter bootstrap modal is causing the modal to be clipped visually.

[image]

This appears to be a Chrome only bug as it does not happen on Firefox or Safari.

I am using: google maps api v3 & twiter bootstrap 3.0.3

**The Html**

```
       <div id="map_picker" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label for="address class="control-label">Address: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="apply_location">Apply</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>  
      </div>
```

**The coffeescript to display the modal**

```
      ($ '#map_picker').on 'shown.bs.modal', () ->
        google.maps.event.trigger window.map, "resize"
```

The map displays with no problems but the rest of the modal is gone. This does not happen for any other modals on the website (viewing pictures and such).There is no extra css or styling. The modal and all elements are placed correctly and all z-indexes appear correct. The input box and button are still functional they are just not drawing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was a maps bug and has resolved itself. I have no changed a line of code or updated chrome.

The map no longer messes with its container. I had frozen the chrome version temporarily for this bug. The only factor that could have change was the maps API. While there is no new API version publicly listed, I was not specifying a version number on that page, so I may have been getting an old version.

I wish I had a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Tryout the .noConflict() method, as below:

```js
var bootstrapModal = $('#map_picker').modal.noConflict();
$('#map_picker').bootstrapMdl = bootstrapModal;
```